# Is it possible to filter on formula used, in Excel?

Tags: excel, filter

Does anyone know if it is possible to set a filter on the formula used rather than on the value returned in Excel. I'm using Excel 2010.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't belong here.

Comment: can you suggest somewhere more appropriate to post it?

Comment: You should use [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a column next to your data add the formula below and change the F2 cell reference to the cell that contains the formula you want to filter on.

```
=FORMULATEXT(F2)
```

Copy the formula down and then filter on the new column.

For earlier versions of Excel that don't have FORMULATEXT you can use the following UDF:

```
Function FORMULATEXT(x As Range)
  FORMULATEXT = x.Formula
End Function
```

Comment: Will this work in Excel 2010??

Comment: Many thanks for your reply, FORMULATEXT doesn't work in Excel 2010 unfortunatley

Comment: Updated by answer to include previous versions

Comment: The UDF works perfectly thanks.

Comment: Excellent - don't forget to except my answer if it has solved your problem.